# Match and show adjacent cell

Tags: match

I have two seperate sheets
Sheet 1 
Column A is a list of Drugs
Column B is the identity code for that drug
Column C is to be the equation

Sheet 2 
Column A is the Idendity code as in B above
Column B is the funding value for this medicine.

I would like to create a function that matched Sheet1 B with Sheet2 A and then prints the value in Sheet2 B on sheet1 C.

Cheers